# Convert from date to long are not the same in java and postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, java-8, timestamp, epoch

I have a table in postgresql which has a column `created_date` date type. I have created the view which returns date in miliseconds instead of date:

```
select date_part('epoch'::text, timezone('UTC'::text, created_date::timestamp with time zone)), created_date
from table
```

This returns the following result:

```
date_part    created_date

1497384000   2017-06-14
1497384000   2017-06-14
1498420800   2017-06-26
1498420800   2017-06-26
```

In Java I did the following:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(view.getStartDate(), formatter);
long longDate = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toEpochSecond();
```

The longDate result is `1497398400` for `2017-06-14` and `1498435200` for `2017-06-26`.

Why postgresql and Java convert from date to long are not the same?

PS: the database's timezone is `Asia/Baku`.

Comment: 24 hours? @pnuts Zone offsets are usually within +/– 14 hours from UTC, so it doesn’t sound likely. Baku is UTC+4:00 all year round.

Comment: While you are correct that two zone offsets may well be 24 hours apart, there is no zone offset in use that is 24 hours different *from UTC*. This is because UTC in pretty much in the middle of all the zone offsets. @pnuts

Comment: That is true, @pnuts

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `atStartOfDay(ZoneId)`. As the `ZoneId` is UTC, it sets the hour to midnight and the zone to UTC. So, your date becomes `2017-06-14T00:00:00Z`, and the equivalent epoch seconds value is `1497398400`.

If you check the value returned by the database (`1497384000`):

```
System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1497384000L));
```

You get:

> 2017-06-13T20:00:00Z

If you convert this to the timezone your system is using (`Asia/Baku`):

```
System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1497384000L).atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Baku")));
```

You get:

> 2017-06-14T00:00+04:00[Asia/Baku]

So, the value `1497384000` is equivalent to `2017-06-13T20:00:00Z` in UTC. The database returns `2017-06-14` because it's converting this UTC date/time to the system's timezone (`Asia/Baku`).

If you want to get the same results, you must use the same timezone the database is using:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2017-06-14", formatter);
// using Asia/Baku timezone instead of UTC
long longDate = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Asia/Baku")).toEpochSecond();
System.out.println(longDate);
```

The output will be:

> 1497384000

Comment: Database timezone is "Asia/Baku"